# How to keep checkbox in page 1 checked when click back from page 2 to page 1, and clear the checked button after refresh page

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

Firstly, I want to keep my checkbox in page 1 checked when I back to page 1 From page 2. Then, I want to make all checked checkbox to be unchecked when I refresh the page.

I have done the first part, which is keep the checkbox checked. But I cannot clear the checked checkbox after I refresh page. Any suggestions?

Here I provide my HTML and jQuery code of page 1:

```js
.on('click', '#btnCancel', function() {
   $('#indexContent').show();
   $('#mainContent').empty();
   $.each(radioValues, function(key, value) {
    $("#" + key).prop('checked', false);
   });
   $.each(checkboxValues, function(key, value) {
    $("#" + key).prop('checked', false);
   });
  }) 

var checkboxValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkboxValues')) || {},
   $checkboxes = $("#myTable :checkbox");
   $checkboxes.on("change", function(){
     $checkboxes.each(function(){
      checkboxValues[this.id] = this.checked;
     });
  
   localStorage.setItem("checkboxValues", JSON.stringify(checkboxValues));
   });
// On page load
  $.each(checkboxValues, function(key, value) {
   $("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
  });
  
  var radioValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('radioValues')) || {},
   $radios = $("#myTable :radio");
   $radios.on("change", function(){
     $radios.each(function(){
      radioValues[this.id] = this.checked;
     });
  
   localStorage.setItem("radioValues", JSON.stringify(radioValues));
   });
// On page load
  $.each(radioValues, function(key, value) {
   $("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="striped" id="myTable">
   <thead>
       <tr>
            <th>Primary</th>
         <th>Tag / Untag</th>
       <th>Accounts</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td><input class="with-gap" name="group1" type="radio" id="tes1"  value="1" />
           <label for="tes1"></label></td>
         <td><input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="filled-in-box1" value="1" />
         <label for="filled-in-box1"></label></td>
         <td><span class="account" id="acc1">123456789</span></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td><input class="with-gap" name="group1" type="radio" id="tes2"  value="2" />
         <label for="tes2"></label></td>
         <td><input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="filled-in-box2"  value="2" />
              <label for="filled-in-box2"></label></td>
         <td><span class="account" id="acc2">147852369</span></td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
</table>

<div class="col-button form-footer">
   <button id="btnCancel"  type="button" name="action" >
    Cancel
   </button>
   <button id="btnNext" type="button" name="action">
    Next
   </button>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hi my friend.**

**Try this in your btnCancel function:**

```
$("#btnCancel").click(function(){
    $('#indexContent').show();
    $('#mainContent').empty();
      $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked',false);
      $('input[type=radio]').prop('checked',false);
});
```

Here is the example code:

https://jsfiddle.net/sosymhuj/1/

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work for me. In my original code, when I click the "Cancel" button, it will back to the main menu, and when I click into page 1, I want the checkboxes remain uncheck. But the checked checkbox still remain checked when I click into page 1 from main menu page.

Comment: where is the button "Cancel"???, its in the same place that the checkboxes?? or in another page.

Comment: The button "Cancel" is in page 1, same page with checkboxes. Sorry that I didn't make my question clear, now I realize that what I want is to reset the checkboxes become unchecked after I refresh my page by pressing "F5". So, is there any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you missed pasting some code but your first script line (`.on('click' ...`) is not valid.

Change it to

```
$('#btnCancel').on('click', function() {
            $('#indexContent').show();
            $('#mainContent').empty();
            $.each(radioValues, function(key, value) {
                $("#" + key).prop('checked', false);
            });
            $.each(checkboxValues, function(key, value) {
                $("#" + key).prop('checked', false);
            });
        })
```

and it should work

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/j0xdeu58/) is the according JSFiddle

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work for me. In my original code, when I click the "Cancel" button, it will back to the main menu, and when I click into page 1, I want the checkboxes remain uncheck. But the checked checkbox still remain checked when I click into page 1 from main menu page.

Comment: Sry but I do not see any 'paging' and your pasted code is not valid JavaScript so currently at least I am not able to help you any further until the question's details are improved.

Comment: Ermm...Is there any way to clear input data of page 1 after I refresh the page?

Comment: <div class="main-menu-button">
      <button id="btnDebitCard" onclick="goToPage('p1.html');" type="button" name="action">
      </button>
     </div>

Comment: Above is the HTML code of my main menu page, when I click the "btnDebitCard", it will go to page 1 and I want the checkboxes in page 1 remain unchecked.